# Firebase y corrutinas de Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, corrutinas

quería saber si existe una manera más eficiente en el siguiente segmento de código. El programa obtiene todos los datos de un nodo de Firestore y pide sus enlaces y sus metadatos, estas se hacen de forma asíncrona son cargadas aun adaptador de RecyclerView, pero estas son cargadas solo si el número de elemntos obtenidos, es igual a la cantidad de elementos que tiene el nodo de Firestore, menos los elementos con algún error. Utilice métodos sincronizados para evitar la sobre escritura a la hora de agregar a la lista.
Estaba pensando en suspender el programa con corrutinas y esperar a que estas finalicen.

```
//metodo de incremento de numero de enlaces rotos
//es sincronizada por que se llamda de forma ansincrona
@Synchronized private fun incrementNumberPhotoLinkError (){
    numberPhotoLinkError++
}

@Synchronized private fun agregarPhoto (photo:Photo,sizeImageTotal: Int){
    listPhoto.add(photo)
    Log.d(VAR_VALUE,"Numero de referencias con error=$numberPhotoLinkError")
    Log.d(VAR_VALUE,"Tamaño de la lista=${listPhoto.size}")
    // se agregan los links al adapterSlider solo si ya se optuvieron todos los links
    //ya que el llamado as asincrono

    if(sizeImageTotal-numberPhotoLinkError==0){
        Log.d(INFO_DEBUG,"No se puedo obtener ninguna  refrecnia a imagen, se pondra una imagen de fondo en la imageSlider")
        setDefautlImageSlider()
    }else if(listPhoto.size== sizeImageTotal-numberPhotoLinkError){
        initImageSlider()
        adapter?.data=listPhoto
        adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

private fun  getImageToReferenceFS(reference: StorageReference,getLinkImgRef: Task<Uri>,sizeImageTotal:Int) {
    if(getLinkImgRef.isSuccessful){
        //el resultado se guarda en "result" que es la url
        reference.metadata.addOnCompleteListener { getMetadata->
            if(getMetadata.isSuccessful){
                agregarPhoto(Photo(getLinkImgRef.result.toString(),
                    getMetadata.result!!.getCustomMetadata("index")?.toInt()!!),sizeImageTotal)
            }
        }
    }else{
        Log.e(ERROR_GET_LINK_FS,
            "Se genero un error al obtener el link de ref=$getLinkImgRef" +
                    "y genero la exception ${getLinkImgRef.exception}")
        incrementNumberPhotoLinkError()
    }

}

private fun initLinksPhotosDB(){
    // obtenecion de los enlacaces de imagenes de la carpeta del id del usuario
    storage.child(firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid+"/").listAll().addOnCompleteListener { getImagenes->
        if(getImagenes.isSuccessful){
            if(getImagenes.result?.items!!.isNotEmpty()){
                Log.d(INFO_DEBUG,"Se obtuvo una lista con ${getImagenes.result?.items!!.size} elementos")
                getImagenes.result?.items?.forEach { imgRef->
                    //al obtener las referencias, la obtenecion d elos links es asincrona
                    imgRef.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener { getLinkImgRef->
                        getImageToReferenceFS(imgRef,getLinkImgRef, getImagenes.result?.items!!.size)
                    }
                }
            }else{
                Log.d(INFO_DEBUG,"Se obtuvo una listPhotoa vacia,se pondra una imagen de fondo standar")
                setDefautlImageSlider()
            }
        }else{
            Log.e(ERROR_ALL_FILES_FS,"No se pudo obtener la listPhotoa de archivos por firestore exception=${getImagenes.exception}")
            setDefautlImageSlider()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago con un contador que me diga si ya terminaron todos, para agregarlo al adapter.

Luego en la Clase foto tiene que haber una variable booleana error.
En error agrego una foto con error.

con eso filtro la lista:

```
listPhoto.filter { it.error == false }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo del pasado, soy yo del futuro, puedes dar un adaptador al principio, en lo que cargan los datos, después esperar los datos utilizando la Liberia extendida de Firestore que soporta corrutinas.
Usas corrutinas para esperar el resultado y después encadenas un iterador sobre los elementos, y al agregarle la palabra "async" indica que harás una corrutina pero no esperaras el valor inmediatamente, esta se almacenara en una lista de llamadas "async" esto es importante para que las llamadas no sean secuenciales pero esperemos a que se llame a todas.
Dentro de él "async" principal puedes hacer esperar los datos de la imagen y el link de forma secuencial o usando subllamadas "async" y al final esperar a obtener los valores con await(), pues en este caso se utilizan para crear los objetos.

Tenemos que tomar en cuenta, que las corrutinas se ejecutan un Dispatchers.IO ya que no hace procesamiento y solo espera a que otras llamadas esperan, y que las corrutinas que generes dentro de corrutinas hereda el Dispatcher. Esto es importante pues después de crear las corrutinas, estas las almacenamos en una lista y esperamos awaitAll() y este espera un propia corrutina y cuando acabemos de esperar cambiamos de contexto, para actualizar la vista principal. Esta forma no es perfecta , ya que se tienen que controlar las excepciones.

Se utiliza lifecycleScope para que no se ejecuten corrutinas después de que la actividad se halla destruido.

```
 //se obtiene los links de las imagenes de perfil
    adapter = PageViewSliderAdapter(null)
    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val deferredList = storage.child(firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid + "/").listAll()
            .await().items.map { refImage ->
            async {
                // estas llamadas pueden ejecutarse en paralelo
                val url = async { refImage.downloadUrl.await().toString() }
                val index =
                    async { refImage.metadata.await().getCustomMetadata("index")?.toInt() }
                //se agrega la foto a una lista
                addPhoto(Photo(url.await(), index.await()))
            }
        }
        // se espera las corrutinas
        deferredList.awaitAll()
        //se ordenan
        listPhoto.sortBy {
            it.index
        }
        //se actualiza el adaptador
        adapter?.data = listPhoto
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            //se actuliza la interfaz
            if (listPhoto.isEmpty()) {
                setDefautlImageSlider()
            } else {
                setImageSlider()
            }
        }
    }
```